# UIViewPropertyAnimation Objective C question

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I'm following WWDC 2017 where explains how to use `UIViewPropertyAnimation` to manage `UIPanGesture` on a `ViewController`.

My project is entirely **Objective C** not **Swift**.

I wanted to have a clarification about this Swift feature:

```
func animateTransitionIfNeeded(forState state: State, duration: TimeInterval) {
let blurAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: duration, dampingRatio: 1) { switch state {
        case .Expanded:
            self.blurEffectView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
        }
        case .Collapsed:
            self.blurEffectView.effect = nil
        }
    }
    blurAnimator.startAnimation()
    runningAnimators.append(blurAnimator)
}
```

At the end of the function it is called:

```
runningAnimators.append(blurAnimator)
```

`runningAnimators` in objective C is it a NSMutableArray or an NSDictionary?

Sorry for the stupid question. Thank you

Comment: In NSDictionary you can not append any element @kAin, so runninfAnimators is array of [UIViewPropertyAnimator] object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an Array of `UIViewPropertyAnimator` objects. This can be "translated" as `NSMutableArray`. You can see the use of `.append` which is a method to add elements to an Array in Swift.

Check [this link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126937-append) for more info about it.

Comment: perfect... Thanks